# チャットルームの作り方は？

Tags: サポート, よくある質問, チャット

作成手順を教えてください。また、チャットルームを作るために必要な権限はありますか？

← [FAQに戻る](/q/1484)

Answer (score 1):

### トピックを決めます

[チャットルームの一覧](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms?tab=site&sort=active&host=ja.stackoverflow.com)で、既に作りたいトピックの部屋がないかを確認します。トピックの例:

- プログラミング言語の部屋: 「Python」
- フレームワークやOSの部屋: 「Symfony」・「iOS」
- サイト上の活動にまつわる部屋: 「タグ職人」

### 作成手順

1. http://chat.stackexchange.com/ に行く
2. 部屋一覧の右下にある「create a new room」ボタンを押す

   [image: create a new room]
3. Room Name (部屋の名前)・Description (説明) 欄を埋める

   [image: 作成フォーム]
4. Related Site (親サイト) が合っていることを確認する

   - 違っていたら、 「more sites...」をクリックして「ja」と入力し、サイトを選ぶ
5. 部屋の種類を確認する

   - Public: 公開ルーム: [必要な権限](/help/privileges/chat)さえあれば、誰でも発言できる部屋。
   - Gallery: 発言制限付きルーム: 部屋の所有者が許可したユーザーのみ発言できる部屋。閲覧は誰でも可能。
6. 「create new room」ボタンを押す

### 宣伝しましょう

- 関連するタグがあれば、そのタグWikiにリンクを貼る
- [サイト全体の部屋](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17893/)に書き込む

### 部屋を作るのに必要な権限

- 公開ルーム: [チャットルームの作成権限](/help/privileges/chat-rooms)が必要です
- 発言制限付きルーム: [ギャラリーチャットルームの作成権限](/help/privileges/gallery-chat-rooms)が必要です