# ゲーム開発者向けの game-development タグの提案

Tags: 討議, タグ

ゲーム開発者向けの game-development タグを提案します。
主に**ツールを使わない**ゲームの実装方法をカテゴライズします。

（注意）Unityでの開発はunityタグを付ければ十分です。両方のタグをつけないで下さい

質問が増えてくると細分化した、例えば下記のようなタグも必要となってきますが現状では development があれば十分かと。
 - game-physics
 - game-collision-detect
 - game-ai
 - game-graphics
 - game-engine
 - game-2d
 - game-3d

---

想定している質問はUnityなどの特定のフレームワークの使い方ではなくゲーム開発における普遍的な実装に関するものです。例えば GameObject-Componentモデル、スキニングの実装、アニメーションの実装、コリジョン検出、空間分割などです。

ここらの深い話が出来るサイトが日本にはありません（2chぐらい？）。
ここら辺のナレッジの集積を怠った事が日本のゲーム開発が欧米に比べて遅れた原因の1つだと思っています。
StackOverFlowが日本のゲーム開発者に役立つナレッジベースになって欲しいと思う。

Comment: game-dev の方がいいかな。流石に長すぎる。

Comment: どういう質問につけることを想定されていますか？「ゲーム開発」で想像される質問の範囲はとても広いので、取り扱いに注意が必要だと思います (タグの説明欄で用途を明確にするなど)。([ヘルプセンターの記事、特に「メタタグについて」のセクション](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)が参考になります)

Comment: そこが実は微妙です。実際本家では game-development はなく細分化された game-engine などの方です。ただ欧米と日本のゲーム開発者では絶対的なアクティブ数が違うので今は game-development だけあればいいかと。

Comment: 想定しているのはゲームの普遍的な実装に関する質問です。例えばUnityタグと一緒に使うわれる事は想定していません。

Comment: 個人的にはアニメーションの実装の質問をするのに`game-development`ではタグが曖昧すぎると思います。万能タグになる恐れがありますので、いちいち細分化してタグ付けをすればいいのではないでしょうか。(developmentという単語自体がひろすぎるのです)

Comment: 広い事は広いです。http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ として独立するレベルの話なので。ただ質問数の多くない日本語版ではそこまで細分化してもしょうがないのかなと。広さ的にはC#などと同じです。
Unityタグと一緒に使われることは想定していませんが絶対に一緒にされると思います。この辺どうしたらいいのか

Answer (score 3):

> 特定のフレームワークの使い方ではなくゲーム開発における普遍的な実装に関するもの

であれば、`game-programming`はどうでしょう。これもちょっと広いとは思いますが。

「Unityと混ぜるのはNG」を伝えるには、タグの要約部分に明示して注意喚起するのが分かりやすいです。タグの要約部分に書いた説明は、タグを選ぶときに表示されます。

ただ、誤用されやすいタグを、それと分かっていながら作ることもないですし、細分化したタグを最初から付けるようにしてよいと思います。

`game-development`のような広義タグを使うデメリットとして、後からタグをお蔵入りさせるには質問を 1 つ 1 つ編集して削除していく必要があり、手間がかかるということがあります。質問が少ないうちに、ゲーム開発に関連する適切なタグのセットを作ることに投資しておいた方が、後々楽だと思います。

またタグには複数の用途があります。

1. 特定の回答者層に向けて質問を知らしめる
2. 質問の文脈を明確にする
3. 似た質問を探しやすくする

とくに 2. は質問が 1 個だけしかない場合でもあてはまるメリットです。細分化されたタグが付いていれば、質問一覧からでもどんなことに関する質問かを把握することができます。

また 3. についても、英語圏に比べ質問は少なくなるだろうとはいえ、最低でも複数人による複数の質問が想定される状況では考慮してよいメリットだと思います。

質問する時の気軽さに関しては、実装について質問する場合は使用言語が大抵の場合決まっていると思います。それをひとまず付けることとすれば、ハードルはそんなに高くないのではないかと想像します。

また、より気軽に質問できる場として、[チャットルーム](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1618/30)を運用するという手もあります。関連する質問を追いやすくするため、ゲーム開発関連のタグがついた質問が新しく投稿されたらチャットルームに流すということもできます。

Comment: タグに関しては Pixv やニコニコ動画を見てると無茶苦茶な使われ方をするのでガイドラインを明示した方がいいですね。ざっと既存のタグを見ましたが、今でもかなり酷い。

Comment: この通り。メタタグを注意してください。メタタグというのは質問の技術を指定するよりも、目的を伝えることです。

タグのあるべき姿はその質問の種類を特定するためです。「game-dev」を追加したとしても、目的のみであるし、その質問をより回答しやすく・探しやすくなりません。「unity」だと、そのライブラリをわかる人が探しやすく、回答の範囲が狭くなりますが、「game-dev」だとそのメリットはありません。

Answer (score 2):

多くのタグがあることについては私は賛成します。

なぜなら、質問者が動揺していたり曖昧なイメージしか持ち合わせていなかったとしても、タグシノニムにより適切なタグへ変換され選択できるからです。

画像は正規表現の例です。
[image: この木なんの木？]

しかし、実際タグを追加するだけでなくタグwikiやタグ詳細、タグ概要を編集し管理すると結構な時間と労力が必要になります。事実、詳細Wikiが未記載のものが数多く存在します。

[タグシノニムも権限の点でハードルが高い仕事です。](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms)
なので、[時間がかかるとは思います](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags)が、誰かに追加させるのではなく自分で追加し、どういう人に使ってもらいたいかタグ詳細に記載するほうが誤解なく運用できるかと思いますがいかがですか。

Comment: 権限の問題でタグそのものを自由に作れない現状では多少不適切なタグでもないより合った方が良いような気がしています。

Comment: @ぽぽたん [その件についてはある程度こちらで議論](http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/1547/%E3%82%BF%E3%82%B0%E3%81%AE%E6%8F%90%E6%A1%88-%E3%82%BF%E3%82%B0%E3%81%8C%E7%8F%BE%E5%9C%A8%E7%84%A1%E3%81%84%E8%B3%AA%E5%95%8F%E7%94%A8%E3%81%AE%E3%82%BF%E3%82%B0%E3%81%AE%E4%BD%9C%E6%88%90)されていて、どうしても今直ぐに必要な場合は、提案し、それ以外は適当につけ適切に直してくれた人を承認するという形のようです。

Answer (score 0):

game-dev、game-physicsのタグを追加しました。

Comment: 自分で書いておいて何ですが省略形ではない game-development の方が良くないですか？

Comment: game-developmentに変更しました。ただ現状どの質問にもこのタグが振られていない状態のため、一定時間が過ぎると削除されるようです。現在このタグの必要性について議論中ですが、必要な場合には適切な質問にタグを振ってください。 http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19753/how-can-we-get-rid-of-misspelled-and-unused-or-zombie-tags

Comment: 自分の質問に付けておきました。これで消えないはず。game-development タグの簡単な説明も書いておきました（承認待ち）。範囲、運用についてはさらに検討の余地あり。

Comment: 質問へのタグ付け、タグの説明追加、ありがとうございます。